# Created Dynamic Link prints to null when app is opened

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a dynamic link manually using a function inside my flutter app. The link that I've created works and it redirects me to the app but when I try to print it on initial load, it doesn't work. I looked at the documentation and I replicated what they said but with no luck.

Function to create link:

```
  Future<void> createDynamicLink(String offerId) async {
      //TODO: Implement for IOS
      var fallbackURL =
          Uri.parse('https://fightertofighter.wixsite.com/ftf-site');

      final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
        link: Uri.parse("https://fighterTOfighter.com?offerId=$offerId"),

        uriPrefix: "https://f2f.page.link",
        androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
            packageName: "com.ftf.ftf", fallbackUrl: fallbackURL),
        // iosParameters: const IOSParameters(bundleId: "com.example.app.ios"),
      );
      final dynamicLink =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);

      print(dynamicLink);

      if (context.mounted) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dynamicLinkSummary',
            arguments: {'link': dynamicLink});
      }
    }
```

main() function

```
  // Check if you received the link via `getInitialLink` first
  final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

  if (initialLink != null) {
    final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;
    // Example of using the dynamic link to push the user to a different screen
  }

  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen(
    (pendingDynamicLinkData) {
      // Set up the `onLink` event listener next as it may be received here
      final Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link;
      // Example of using the dynamic link to push the user to a different screen
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path); //also this complains about the context as being undefined
    },
  );

  print(initialLink); //always returns NULL
```

Also context inside Navigator complains that it is undefined but in Firebase documentation, it seems to be working fine..

I've also added the SHA1 and SHA256 in firebase